# Custom SQL Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Consider I have a model -

```
    public class Student
    {
         public int id {get; set;}
         public string name {get; set;}
    }
```

And I would want to map this using EF with custom query ( My actual query would have few joins and some where conditions in it)

```
    Select id, name from student
```

Now I know that we can accomplish the same with

```
    using(......)
    {
    var students = Context.Students.SqlQuery("Select id, name from student").ToList<Student>();
    .....
    }
```

But what if I would want to map the DbSet Students with Student always. Meaning can I use it like how we use EntityTypeConfiguration. Instead of writing the query every time I access?

Do we have something like entity type configuration mapping for custom query.

(Note: EF 6.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `SqlQuery` at all. `Students` property within your context is already `IEnumerable<Student>`, so you can just call `ToList()` on it and get all items from db table.

```
var students = Context.Students.ToList();
```

Of course, I assumed your context is set right and `Students` property is of type `DbSet<Student>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. My context is not set. You mean I have set the mapping right? No  I have not. I would want to use custom query. Lets say join of 3 tables result should be going to a DbSet

Comment: Create a view on you database and map it into EF context.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that was the first thought, but due to some constraints, I am not able to.

Comment: One of the main reasons being I have 100 + databases and trying to connect all these. (Dynamic connection string.)

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is already in your context. Welcome to the wonderful world of LINQ and Entityframwork!

This will bring back the students:

```
var Students = (from a in Context.Students select a).ToList();
```

This will bring back a list of their ids

```
 var Students = (from a in Context.Students select a.id).ToList();
```

And this will bring back students named Joe

```
 var Student = (from a in Context.Students where a.name.equals("Joe") select a).ToList);
```

....and so on

You can make any changes to the items in your retrieved list and have them pushed to the database by calling `Context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Thank you. I have not done the model binding yet. I would want to use custom query. Lets say join of 3 tables result should be going to a DbSet